# SWING disable or hide scroll bar, but enable wheel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollbar

I would like to disable or hide the scrollbar in a JScrollPane, but let the user scroll up and down with the mouse wheel. 
If I use verticalScrollBarPolicy(NEVER) it hides the scroll bar, so it's Ok, but can't use the wheel.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Where is your [mcve]? You were asked for one in your last question.

Comment: @camickr How would an MCVE help anyone provide an answer to this?  Any potential respondent _either_ knows how to enable the wheel while hiding the scroll bar, _or_ they don't.  Please don't encourage querents to post loads of irrelevant code.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I would argue that having some idea of what the OP is doing is very important as it, in of it self, can provide the answer to the question, as well as the fact, that it helps others from having to work up there own solution, which, in many cases, posters won't agree to because "it doesn't fit what they have", and don't think it doesn't happen. And since the OP is continuing to double post there question, there is another issue

Comment: What if the user doesn't have a mouse wheel?

Comment: [There is an answer here which should solve your issue](https://coderanch.com/t/541896/java/Scrolling-mouse-wheel-scrollpane-scrollbar)

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, `How would an MCVE help anyone provide an answer to this?` - The OP made a statement that they wrote some code and it didn't work. So, the code should be posted so we can verify if they are doing anything wrong. `don't encourage querents to post loads of irrelevant code.` - I'm asking for an `MCVE`, The MCVE would be less than 10-15 lines of code. All the OP needs to do is create a frame, add a component, like a JTable with 50 rows to the frame and see how scrolling works. The whole point if for the OP to make sure the problem has been simplified BEFORE asking the question.

Comment: ... Then if the MCVE still doesn't work you have simple code to post which shows us you made a real effort to solve the problem. Read the OP's last question and you will see they made a false claim about dragging a component in a scrollpane when a the scrollbar is not visible. So the OP loses credibility when then ask a question without proof it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I haven't seen you on JavaRanch before. Or, at least I haven't associated a different user name with your question answering style :)

Comment: @camickr Never made it to JavaRanch, made the Java Forums and Java Net WAY back in the day. I just did what the OP apparently didn't do - I did a google search ;)

Comment: @camickr I disagree with you, but these comments are probably not the right place for this discussion.  I will most likely post on the meta some time later, which would probably be a better place to talk.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem `I disagree with you` - My recommendation is what is suggested by the majority of users who spend their time answering Swing related questions.

Comment: lmao this is so autistic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Based on this answer from CodeRanch](https://coderanch.com/t/541896/java/Scrolling-mouse-wheel-scrollpane-scrollbar), scrolling is disabled when the scroll bars are never shown.  You need to override the `JScrollBar`s `isVisible` property to "trick" into scrolling.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Scrollable;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(new TestPane());
                JScrollBar scrollBar = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL) {

                    @Override
                    public boolean isVisible() {
                        return true;
                    }
                };
                // if appropriate, uncomment
                //scrollBar.putClientProperty("JScrollBar.fastWheelScrolling", Boolean.TRUE);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBar(scrollBar);
                scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                frame.add(scrollPane);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        public TestPane() {
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 800);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
            Integer lineY = null;
            for (int yPos = fm.getAscent(); yPos < getHeight(); yPos += 30) {
                g2d.drawString(Integer.toString(yPos), 10, yPos + fm.getAscent());
                if (lineY != null) {
                    g2d.drawLine(15, lineY, 15, yPos);
                }
                lineY = yPos + fm.getAscent();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 64;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

You don't need to use `Scrollable`, it is used here purely for demonstration purposes to test the theory.

This, however, also stops calling `getScrollableUnitIncrement`, which may affect the overall speed of the scrolling, something you'll have to investigate further

Oh, there are also other caveats, if one or more components contained in the `JScrollPane` registers to the `MouseWheelListener` events, it will stop the scroll pane from been notified

Answer (score 1):

Based on the same answer cited from CodeRanch by @MadProgrammer, I get it working with a simpler solution:

```
public class OnlyHorizontalJScrollPane extends JScrollPane {
    @Override
    public JScrollBar createVerticalScrollBar() {
        JScrollBar verticalScrollBar = new JScrollPane.ScrollBar(1);
        verticalScrollBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,0));
        return verticalScrollBar;
    }
}
```

I tested it on Windows, java 14.

Comment: or, simply, `myScrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));`, where `myScrollPane` is an instance of a `JScrollPane`.